# RN Android - cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I know there are already plenty of the same issues open here. But none of the answers fixed my issue.

[image: app image]

My App is working in Web, but NOT on Android. Here I get this error:

[image: RCTVirtualText error]

This is the `View` of my search:

```
<View>
  <Input
    placeholder='Search urls'
    leftIcon={
      <Icon
        name='user'
        size={24}
        color='black'
      />
    }
    onChangeText={(searchtext) => (filter = searchtext)}
  />
  <Button title='OK' onPress={() => getLinks({ variables: { searchtext: filter } })}>OK</Button>
  <View>
    {data && 
      data.feed.links.map((link, index) => (
        <Text><Linky key={link.id} link={link} index={index}/></Text>
      ))
    }
  </View>
</View>
```

But the error is in the inner `View`

```
  <View>
    {data && 
      data.feed.links.map((link, index) => (
        <Text><Linky key={link.id} link={link} index={index}/></Text>
      ))
    }
  </View>
```

So if I say:

```
  <View>
    <Text>This works on Android!</Text>
  </View>
```

it works on web and Android. To fix this issue, most of the time there is a comment somewhere or a typo. But in my case I cannot find anything.

Ok concerning:

```
<Text><Linky key={link.id} link={link} index={index}/></Text>
```

you might want to know what is in that `Linky` component. Here it is:

```
class Linky extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
    return (
      <Mutation
        mutation={VOTE_MUTATION}
        variables={{ linkId: this.props.link.id }}
        update={(store, { data: { vote } }) =>
          this.props.updateStoreAfterVote(store, vote, this.props.link.id)
        }
      >
        {voteMutation => (
          <View>
            <Text>{this.props.index + 1}.</Text>
            <Text>{this.props.link.description}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </Mutation>
    )
  }
}
```

I cannot see any comment or typo here as well. I have no idea what causes that error on the Android device.

Comment: I think React Native doesn't support including anything else expect simple text or ```Text``` component inside another ```Text``` component.

Comment: So your tips is to prefill it in a function to a variable and then simply print the variable in the return?

Comment: First, I don't understand why you need to put ```Linky``` component inside ```Text```? Why you can't use ```Linky``` component without wrapping it with ```Text```?

Comment: MY project is based on https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo/blob/master/src/components/Link.js and https://github.com/howtographql/react-apollo/blob/master/src/components/Search.js but yes, I'm going to try it a bit different, compared to that boilerplate.

Comment: Was able to solve it. Indeed, I repeated the Text. So I have View > Text > Text for some reason. Makes sense to get that error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a duplication of `Text` as the `Linky` also returns `Text`.

So this was easy to fix by replacing:

```
<Text><Linky key={link.id} link={link} index={index}/></Text>
```

with

```
<Linky key={link.id} link={link} index={index}/>
```